# Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've just used create-react-app to start a new typescript react app and then installed firebase. I ran `firebase init`, selected the typescript option, enabled es lint  and enabled functions.

As soon as I uncommented the boilerplate function code in functions/index.ts, I noticed some warnings in VS Code...

functions/eslintrc.js:

[image]

Giving error: **"Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided"**

functions/tsconfig.json:

[image]

functions/src/index.ts:

[image]

giving error: **"Parsing error: Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'.eslint"**

functions/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I don't understand these errors. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The first error from TypeScript ESLint is related to not being able to find a project `tsconfig.json` that matches your functions.

To fix this, we need to tell TypeScript ESLint where the other `tsconfig.json` is by editing your `parserOptions`.

**`.eslintrc.js`**

```js
// [...]
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
  "project": [
    "./tsconfig.json",
    "./functions/tsconfig.json",
  ]
}
// [...]
```

To fix the parsing issue related to JSX for your React files, you must add the [`jsx` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage) to your `tsconfig.json` configurations that include JSX. This will likely be your non-function configuration, and you will most likely need to set it to `react-jsx` for React v17+ or `react` in all other cases for Create React App.

**`tsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
    // [...]
  }
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: How does this help for the problem? I tried this but I still have the same problem inside my functions/src folder. It would be great to know what settings in the `functions/tsconfig.json` and what settings in the `functions/.eslintrc.js`have to be done. To me the problem seems to be some vscode issue, since `npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint` is working as expected with the firebase generated `.eslintrc.js` file.

Comment: It fixes the original poster's issues by telling the TypeScript ESLint parser to use the two different tsconfigs, and the tsconfg matching the React source has the jsx flag switched on. As for your other gaps with applying my answer to your setup, it varies, so I cannot say what your entire configuration should be. It may be worth noting my answer includes the necessary changes to the files posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

further to the above excellent suggestion by Evelyn Hathaway , and after I installed just the functions with no hosting and I changed the ".eslingrc.js:  file

FROM

```
 .eslingrc.js
    parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json",
   "tsconfig.dev.json"],
```

to

```
.eslingrc.js
   parserOptions: {
   project: ["./functions/tsconfig.json",
   "./functions/tsconfig.dev.json"],
```

At last the seemed to work after I spent a frustrating day.....