# Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project config. (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

### The problem

Hi, I'm currently setting up a new directory with some linting required but when I set up the `eslintrc.json` I get this error `"parserOptions.project\" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.\nThe file does not match your project config: test/src/app.ts The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.`

**This issue is purely isolated to VSCode and doesn't occur if I run eslint via the console.**

### What I have tried

As per these two links I've found via some google searches:

1. ["parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser)
2. [Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser. The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876864/parsing-error-parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parse)

I have double checked that I have installed the parser and also ensured the `eslintrc.json` has the path to my `tsconfig` which is in the same directory.

### My Code

#### `eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "jest": false
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
      "project": "tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": ["error", { "default": "array-simple" }],
    "@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "error"
  }
}
```

#### `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ]
}
```

My file structure is like this

```
test
 - src (folder)
   - app.ts
 - eslintrc.json
 - tsconfig.json
 - package-lock.json
 - package.json
```

Any assistance would be really appreciated, I'll be sticking around if there are any clarifications needed or other questions. Thank you

Comment: You show a file called "tsconfig.js" but then say that you have "tsconfig.json" in your file structure. And is the error showing in the console or in your editor? If you're seeing the error in the console, what is the command you have entered?

Comment: My bad that is just a typo. The error is being picked up as  `problem` by VS Code rather than any specific command. If I lint using `eslint './src/**/*{ts,tsx}` this error doesn't show up.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your setup but my VSCode is not showing any errors. I think you already tried to quit it and run it again?

Comment: Yes, i've restarted VSCode just in case it hadn't refreshed properly.